# How do I remap a dataframe with a dict containing nested list using map function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID
0   123
1   123
2   123
3   123
4   123
5   123
6   456
7   456
8   456
9   123
```

I want to add a new column with `map` function using dict d:

```
d = {'123': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5], '456': [1, 2, 1]}
```

Expected output:

```
    ID  Count
0   123   1
1   123   2
2   123   3
3   123   1
4   123   2
5   123   1
6   456   1
7   456   2
8   456   1
9   123   5
```

But `df.ID.map(d)` returns:

```
0    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
1    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
2    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
3    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
4    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
5    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
6             [1, 2, 1]
7             [1, 2, 1]
8             [1, 2, 1]
9    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: map with dict can only do with unique key , and you target df have multiple duplicates

Comment: Thanks BENY! What can I use instead of map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`+`apply`:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: pd.Series(d[g.name]))
```

Example:

```
>>> df['Count'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: pd.Series(d[g.name])).to_list()
>>> df
    ID  Count
0  123      1
1  123      2
2  123      3
3  123      1
4  123      2
5  123      1
6  456      1
7  456      2
8  456      1
```

##### edit. variant for unordered input:

```
(df.join(df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: pd.Series(d[g.name],
                                                    name='Count',
                                                    index=g.index))
           .droplevel(0))
)
```

output:

```
    ID  Count
0  123      1
1  123      2
2  123      3
3  123      1
4  123      2
5  123      1
6  456      1
7  456      2
8  456      1
9  123      5
```

Comment: Thanks mozway! I added a row with id 123 at the end of the data and run the code but I didn't get the expected result. That is, if the data is unordered your code isn't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example (input/output) for this case? (Edit the question)

Comment: I editted. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but I had to change `'123'` (string) to `123` (int). It depends on the type that you have in your data.

Answer (score 0):

From you dict you can get what you need after `explode`

```
pd.Series(d).explode().reset_index()
Out[115]: 
  index  0
0   123  1
1   123  2
2   123  3
3   123  1
4   123  2
5   123  1
6   456  1
7   456  2
8   456  1
```

Comment: Great one but this doesn't work if the original `df` has a different order. Example `123 456 123 456`.

Comment: @mozway Great one you too. If BENY's answer works for OP that's good I just wanted to point out the caveat while using this one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cumulative count on `df` -> the assumption here is that the count for each ID should be the same as the count of values for each ID in d :

```py
df = df.assign(counter = df.groupby('ID').cumcount())
```

Build a dataframe from `d`, using pd.concat:

```py
# converted the keys to integers
# so that it matches the dtype of ID in df
frame = pd.concat([pd.Series(val) for _, val in d.items()], 
                  keys = map(int, d))
frame.name = 'Count'
```

Run a `pd.merge` to align `frame` to `df`:

```py
df.merge(frame, 
        left_on = ['ID', 'counter'], 
        right_index = True).drop(columns='counter')

    ID  Count
0  123      1
1  123      2
2  123      3
3  123      1
4  123      2
5  123      1
6  456      1
7  456      2
8  456      1
9  123      5
```